# CodeIgniter hooks cause automaticaly logout(kill the session)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using CodeIgniter hooks, I'm trying to trigger an action before a controller to be executed(pre_controller) and another action after the controller to be executed. But I'm facing a weird situation, when I enable the hook in `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;` it trigger automatic logout, I mean it  kills the user session. Could some one helps me on this? May be I made a wrong configuration for the hook.

Here is the hooks configuration:
     hooks.php

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'Hookcall',
                                'function' => 'get_post_params',
                                'filename' => 'hookcall.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
/*
  hook for saving fraude logs
*/
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'Hookcall',
                                'function' => 'save_logs',
                                'filename' => 'hookcall.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

Comment: The hooks configuration itself can't break anything. The problem must be inside the code actually executed by your hooks.

Comment: Make sure there is no `session_destroy` inside `hookcall.php` file or something.

Comment: @mega6382  there is no `session_destroy` as you can see in the code below I kept empty methods in `hookcall.php`. But the issue still happening   `<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Hookcall extends MY_Controller
{
    public function save_logs()
    {

    }
    public function get_post_params()
    {

    }
    private function get_files_superior_5_percent($params)
    {
        
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Hookcall should NOT extend MY_Controller. It should be a simple class instead

```
class Hookcall
{
    public function save_logs()
    { 
    } 

    public function get_post_params() 
    { 
    } 

    private function get_files_superior_5_percent($params)
    { 
    } 

}
```